# How can I print name of corrent page using php?

Tags: php, filenames, echo

How can I print name of corrent page using php ?

```
echo $corrent_page_name;
```

Result should be :

```
index.php
```

Comment: You should be able to find this on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$corrent_page_name = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

See the PHP manual for [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) for more information.

You could also use [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) such as:

```
$corrent_page_name = basename(__FILE__);
```

Comment: +1 for a correct solution *and* replicating the OP's typo on purpose. :)

Comment: @faressoft see updated answer with links to the relevant PHP manual pages.

Comment: @faressoft Gets you the substring after the final directory separator http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: @faressoft if this post helped you please mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$current_page_name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Also, you can use this to include any GET variables in the URL:

`$current_page_name = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

EDIT: Sorry. I misunderstood the question. I'll leave this here anyway for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

$current_page_name = end(explode("/",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]));